Asymptotic differential equation
This is probably a stupid question, but suppose $x f'\sim -f$ in the sense that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x f'(x)}{f(x)} = -1$.
The solution to $xf' = -f$ is of the form $f(x) = Cx^{-1},$ so it is tempting to conclude that $f \asymp x^{-1}.$ But as multiple questions on this site have pointed out, integration does not preserve asymptotic equivalence.
What, if anything, can we say about the asymptotic behavior of $f(x),$ then? Do any additional restrictions on $f(x)$ guarantee $f\asymp x^{-1}$?

I notice that $\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ goes to zero faster than $x^{-1}$, that the solution of $x f' = -f + \mathrm{e}^x$ is $f(x) = (C - \mathrm{e}^{-x})/x$, satisfying your limit.  I expect you can add anything in $o(x^{-1})$ to your solution.

If you add a term $o(x^{-1})$ to $f$ then that term is subleading and we still have $f\asymp x^{-1},$ no?

If $f>0$ L'Hospital yields $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log(f(x))}{\log(x)}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}=-1$. So at least $\log(f(x)) \asymp \log(x^{-1})$.
